# SoftLayer slcli capture image with multiple SAN disks

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I would like to create a SoftLayer image of an existing VM using the slcli vs capture command. A single disk works fine but I'm unable to capture an image with 2 or more SAN disks. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
$ slcli virtual capture 15193387 --all True -n myImageTemplateAll
```

replace 15193387 with the id of your VSI

The “--all” option adds all the disk in the image template.

Comment: Thank you... That worked. But I got an error with a VM with a small metadata disk. Here's the error: "Invalid block device supplied. Please be sure to not include any metadata disk block devices." Is there a work-around? Thanks again!

Comment: That sound like an issue a recommed you report it here https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue

Comment: Will do... Thanks so much for your help!